# Get unique elements from list row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have a column with annotations of sentences in IOB format.
A row looks roughly like this:

```
data['labels'][0] = '['O', 'O', 'O', 'B-l1', 'O', 'B-l1', 'I-l2', 'I-l2', 'O', 'I-l2']'
```

I want to get the unique labels: `'O'`, `'B-l1'`, and `'I-l2'`. The idea is to remove all rows that are not annotated, meaning the only label in the list is `'O'`.

This is my current code:

```
list(set(data['labels][0]))
```

But it returns each symbol on a new row:

```
'O',
'B',
'-',
'l',
'1',
'I',
'2',
','
```

which is not what I am looking for.

I would appreciate some help here. Thanks.

Comment: `list(set(data['labels']))` ?

Comment: `data["labels"].apply(lambda x: set(i for i in x if "-" not in i))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter your rows, you can use set operations:

```
S = {'O'}

data[[not S.issuperset(l) for l in data['labels']]]
```

Example input:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'labels': [['O'], ['O', 'B-l1'], []]})
```

Output:

```
      labels
1  [O, B-l1]
```

##### converting from strings

If you have strings representations of lists:

```
import ast

data['labels'] = [list(set(ast.literal_eval(l))) for l in data['labels']]
```

Comment: I need the unique labels per row. And for some reason, I don't get the unique labels with this code even though I copy-pasted it.

Comment: I thought you wanted to filter the rows. To get unique values: `data['labels'] = [list(set(l)) for l in data['labels']]`. You can then perform filtering of you want both.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did but the return result is: `'O', 'B', 'l', '1', '2', '-', ','` And when I get specific row it is returned as a list in single quotes. for example, `data['labels'][0]` returns the list in single quotes like this: `'['O', 'O', 'O', 'B-l1', 'O', 'B-l1', 'I-l2', 'I-l2', 'O', 'I-l2']'`

Comment: Then your real data is not what you showed. This means that you have a string. You can convert using `ast.literal_eval`. `data['labels'] = [list(set(ast.literal_eval(l))) for l in data['labels']]`

Comment: lifesaver :) Thank you. I will edit my question, to make it clearer for the other people. Can you add your solution to the answer above?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
lst = ['O', 'O', 'O', 'B-l1', 'O', 'B-l1', 'I-l2', 'I-l2', 'O', 'I-l2']

np.unique(lst).tolist()
```

Output:

```
['B-l1', 'I-l2', 'O']
```